# たら at the end of a compound sentence

Tags: meaning, て-form, conditionals

I'm wondering if there's a sentence:

> AしてBしてCされたら

would the meaning be:

**if** A, B, C...

or

A, B, **if** C...

Comment: Is that supposed to be a complete sentence with たら coming “at the end” as you say, or is it supposed to be only the first part of a sentence? Also, is it intentional that A and B are used in active voice and C is in passive voice? In any case a concrete example would help.

Comment: You have asked an interesting question about 'scope' without perhaps realizing it. By 'scope', in this instance, is meant 'over what constituents of the sentence does the sense of -tara operate', is it just the last verb in the sequence or is the whole sequence part of a -tara clause? As the answer has pointed out, it may depend on sense, but also may be ambiguous. You should also be aware that scope problems can arise for foreign learners, with ーば, Sと, だろう at the end of a sentence, or the negative ーない.

Answer (score 0):

You should be a bit more specific in your question, though I understand it's hard when you're considering hypotheticals.

I've went ahead and found sentences online:

> 明日買い物して一晩寝たら出発の予定だ
>
> We'll go shopping tomorrow and leave after a night's sleep.

[Source](https://ncode.syosetu.com/n1633dr/328/)

Here, note that the して is part of the left side of the たら clause. Note that here たら means "after", not "if", but it still means something like "A and B, and then after, C" (the first option you proposed).

> あなたもそんな無理をしてお金を使ったら駄目ですよ。
>
> You can't force yourself to spend money like that either.

[Source](https://ncode.syosetu.com/n2617fy/58/)

This specific construction doesn't seem to be overly popular (or the engines I'm using aren't particularly good at finding it). In general, it seems that the て form is the sub-clause inside the たら clause, probably because constructing a reason for it to be interpreted that way is hard. I'd be more than happy to hear a native's opinion though.

I guess, just keep in mind that which clause a part of a sentence is part of might not always be easy to distinguish. It's definitely not out of the question for it to be parsed the other way.

Comment: Perhaps あなたもそんな無理をして病気になったらどうするんですか would be a better example explaining your second construction.